# Can we use parse server for postgresql

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, parse-server

Currently I am using MongoDB with parse-server as back-end in my **node.js** application, because of business requirement I have to change my database from **mongodb** to **postgresql**. Is there any way by which I can use parse-server with postgresql?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. Just make use of the `Postgres adapter`. Only downside is the documentation is lacking.  The adapter however has passed most of the tests.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/tree/deedf7b370a8b133d5b8573369e1058973616ef1/src/Adapters/Storage/Postgres